# Why doesn't this array render?

Tags: support, mathjax

Why doesn't

```
 $$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}

 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
 \hline

 1& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\

 2& 2 & 1 & 5 & 3 & 4 \\

 3& 3 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 2 \\

 4& 4 & 5 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\

 5& 5 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 1
 \end{array}$$
```

for

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}

& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \
\hline

1& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \

2& 2 & 1 & 5 & 3 & 4 \

3& 3 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 2 \

4& 4 & 5 & 2 & 1 & 3 \

5& 5 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 1
\end{array}$$

render in MathJax/$\LaTeX$?

Comment: [Here's the motivating question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2227065/104041)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe it’s all those unnecessary line breaks?

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
1& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
2& 2 & 1 & 5 & 3 & 4 \\
3& 3 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 2 \\
4& 4 & 5 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
5& 5 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 1
\end{array}$$

Comment: Right, the line breaks are causing each line to be wrapped in `<p>...</p>`, which means MathJax won't see it as one expression (math can't have HTML tags in the middle of it.